What kind of clause does the "as" introduce
I am reading an English book, and there are two sentences that confuse me.

This opposition at once engenders the driveto transform the object as it is into the object as it ought to be.

For that state of the self as it wavers between ideal and object is a state of feeling, since it is a state of being restricted for
itself.


I almost know the meaning of these two sentences. But I am not sure what kind of clauses these are.

The "object as it is" = the way the object is now. "As it wavers" = At the time the object moves.

When as does the job of a conjunction, it introduces a dependent clause.

@YosefBaskin "Dependent clause" tells us about the grammatical relations,not what type of clause it is, though.

Oxford Dictionary of English, courtesy of Google, lists these two usages:

as ... [conjunction]

used to indicate by comparison the way that something happens or is done [or is, was, will be, ought to be].


they can do as they wish


used to indicate that something happens during the time when something else is taking place.


Frank watched him as he ambled through the crowd

Similar: while / just as / even as / at the (same) time that / at the
moment that /  during the time that / just when / simultaneously

I've re-ordered the senses to match the examples in the question.
In the object as it is / as it ought to be, the noun / determiner group the object is post-modified by the as-string. In ODE's example, the clause 'they can do' is addressed. These would traditionally have been distinguished as adjectival and adverbial functions respectively. But the usage here (NP + as + Clause) is not that of either a prototypical preposition, conjunction, or adverb.
The CGEL interpretation, I believe, given by BillJ on ELL (!), is:

Something is [as we would like it to be].

{Compare

Something is [as it ought to be].}

... "as" is here a preposition in a comparative construction where there is a comparison between two states.
The clause "we would like it to be" functions as complement of "as", and the as-phrase functions as predicative complement of "be" (i.e. "is").

Hmmm. It's not an independent clause though, is it? And there's a manadatory gap after the be:  *Everything is as it ought to be that way is ungrammatical. So you need to explain what type of clause it is after the word as, as requested by the OP.
